# Ocultar errores a usuario final usando Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, web

estoy empezando con Laravel, me salió el error que abajo muestro, ya está solucionado, el detalle es que no encuentro la manera de que cuando ocurra un error no se muestre todos esos detalles en el navegador. Me podrían ayudar con la configuración de Laravel? Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es recomendable escribir código que atrape y gestione los errores durante la ejecución del programa.

La opción `debug` en el archivo de configuración `config/app.php` es la que determina cuanta información acerca un error es mostrada al usuario.

Podes modificar el valor de la variable de entorno `APP_DEBUG`, la cual se almacena en tu archivo `.env`, pasandole un booleano para activar o desactivar esta característica.

A la hora de desarrollar se la asigna el valor `true` y cuando la aplicación esta en producción se le asigna `false` para evitar exponer información sensible a los usuarios.

[Manejo de errores](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#configuration)